# How to delete reference of image file?

Tags: iphone

I have used test images for my developing process and now I want to change my test images to another images. so I deleted the whole test image folder and change to new folder. But it still shows old images. How do I remove these reference from old images and use new images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clean your project (in the Xcode menu) images are cached when building and never go away when you want them to.

Comment: Its 'clean all target' listed in build menu. thanks for the idea :-)